# What is the simplest way to determine whether or not a one dimensional array of strings contains nothing but zero length strings?

Tags: vb.net, arrays, string

The obvious first thought is:

```
Public Function CheckStrings(ByVal input As String()) As Boolean
    For Each s As String In input
        If s.Length > 0 Then Return True
    Next
    Return False
End Function
```

I'm sure there is a simpler way than that though.  At least simpler in terms of the code if not necessarily the performance.

**End result:**

Well, you guys did a pretty good job of simplifying. Well done.
I think I'll still use an extension to make it just that much simpler in the main code. The final result really isn't too bad by itself though.

Here's my final code:

```
<Extension()> _
Public Function AnyNonZero(ByVal value As String()) As Boolean
    If Not value.All(Function(x) String.IsNullOrEmpty(x)) Then Return True
    Return False
End Function
```

Comment: That's pretty simple already.

Comment: It is, but I feel like there should be an input.NonZero() kind of simple method. I could just create an extension method using the above code but I'm betting one of the existing methods could be used very simply if I just knew how to use it.

Comment: Your function currently returns true if there is a string with a length greater than zero, and false if all strings are zero length - is that what you want?  Based on your question, I would think you'd want it the other way around.

Comment: You might be able to do it in less lines with LINQ, but I don't know if I'd consider that easier or not.  Right now you have a good balance between simple and readable.  LINQ still throws some developers for a loop (no pun intended).

Comment: Ah yes I suppose I did word it kind of oddly. I just think of the function as checking if there is anything in there. If there is, it's true. If there is not, it's false.

Comment: I'm basically looking for something very similar to string.any but not including elements that are a zls.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this to return true if all elements are zero length.

```
Dim inputIsEmpty As Boolean = Array.TrueForAll(input, Function(x) x.Length = 0)
```

Be careful of null references.  You may want to use this instead:

```
Dim inputIsEmpty As Boolean = Array.TrueForAll(input, Function(x) String.IsNullOrEmpty(x))
```

Comment: Ah yes, eliminates the need for the Function dec in John's answer. Still not quite as simple as I was envisioning. Lamda never seems simple to me. One line is great though.

Comment: Hard to choose an answer because all 3 were very helpful but I think you contributed the most. Thanks for the input.

Answer (score 2):

How about this? It uses your string array named input.

```
Array.TrueForAll(input, AddressOf ZeroLengthString)

Private Function ZeroLengthString(ByVal s As String) As Boolean
    Return s.Length = 0
End Function
```

Comment: That's pretty smart. I hadn't noticed the "TrueForAll" method.

Comment: I think Hand-E-Food's answer just eliminates the need for the Function dec using lamda. That simplifies things further.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a Linq function similar to Array.TrueForAll:

```
Dim allEmpty = values.All(Function(x) x.Length = 0)
```

I find it to be a bit more easily readable than Array.TrueForAll.

Comment: Agreed, that is yet another improvement. Thanks